# Java: executing a showOptionDialog in another Thread and then exiting from it makes closing the entire application

Tags: java, macos, swing, dialog

I implemented the following code to run a dialogue event with swing in Java in another thread while my program does things.

```
public class othermain implements Runnable {

    public void displayDialog() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Insert text");
        TextField text = new TextField(15);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(text);
        String[] options = new String[]{"Cancel", "Ok"};
        int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Ask",
                JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                null, options, options[1]);
        if (option == 1) {
            System.out.println(text.getText());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.displayDialog();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        othermain a = new othermain();
        //a.load();
        Thread th = new Thread(a);
        th.start();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("I should never exit from the cycle");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}
```

This works but the problem is that on macOS once opened the dialog box, the icon of the program remains in the dock, so when I try to close it my entire application gets closed even if the dialogue has been executed in another thread. In other words, I expected that only the thread where the dialogue has executed should have closed **after pressed ok button or cancel button**.
How can I avoid the behaviour described and making the icon hidden, showing only the message box and not the icon of the program too so that it cannot be closed manually? Or if this cannot be avoided when quitting the app manually should be closed only the thread that is executing it and not the entire application.

Current Output:

```
I should never exit from the cycle
I should never exit from the cycle
I should never exit from the cycle
text
I should never exit from the cycle

Process finished with exit code 0 //When I quit the application from the dock
```

[image]

Comment: Event though you can display a `JOptionPane` in a java console application, that is not its intended purpose. All _Swing_ code **must** run on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). I think you should either make you application a GUI application or find an alternative to using `JOptionPane` for getting input from the user.

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions. TextField is an AWT component. User JTextField with Swing.

Comment: @camickr this is just an example posted to explain the problem. I used JTextField in the real scenario too. Please don’t write off-topic things just to write something.

Comment: @Abra so do you have a practical example which solves the problem?

Comment: (1-) @Virgula, the code you post should be the code you are testing. So the code should be proper and conform to standards. We can't guess if you are making a silly mistake or not. You are the one asking for help so make the information as accurate as possible. There is no excuse to be lazy.

Comment: Consider using either class [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) or class [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

Comment: @Abra unfortunately this doesn't help.The terminal will be not displayed so the interaction needs be done with a GUI messagebox. The only feature that I need is avoiding to close the application when I click quit from the dock icon (by hiding it or in other ways). The rest works fine.

Comment: @Abra Thank you very much for your tips. I solved with a trick posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are wondering about this problem, I solved with this trick.

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

Main updated:

```
//Code for messagebox is the same 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");
    java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    othermain a = new othermain();
    a.displayDialog();
    //Thread th = new Thread(a); //You don't need to run in a separated thread now
    //th.start();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("I should never exit from the cycle");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

*Special thanks to the user who said me to "follow the Java conventions" ***without adding a single additional word about the problem***. He helped me a lot, just like so many users who answer like him.*